# How to override the styles in iframe of canvasApp component ..?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, css

I am using CanvasApp component in page. In this i am attaching and displaying the videos from external. I am trying to override the height of the video using the custom css. But height is not overriding. CanvasApp have two iframes outer and inner. Inner iframe have html and body tags. In this inner iframe body video is displaying. If we give the html and body height as 100% in browser console(means Inspect Element) video height increased. But i am not able override inner iframe html, body using css. How can i override this..

Comment: Check second answer here, this seems to be a little hack
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-override-body-style-for-content-in-iframe

Comment: Hi Vladyslav Kushney, I tried with that solution but it's not worked for me.

Comment: Than it is not possible to access iframe of another domain because of security.
Do you have access to source code of page that you load as iframe? If you can modify it, there is a way to establish communication bitween iframe and main page with javascript. And you can change styles with javascript.